# Update properties that reference another model without duplication

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to create an event list where users can add and remove themselves from events and specify if they are bringing guests with them to that event.

So I have an event schema and a user schema, where the event schema is referencing the user schema. So when a new event is created users can add themselves to that event with their ids.

Now I'm trying to make it so that users can also include guests. How Do I achieve that?

**Here's an example**

User Schema:

```
let UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    lowercase: true,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },
    name:{
    type: String,
    require: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
...
```

Event Schema:

```
let EventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  date: {
    type: Date,
    unique: true,
    timestamps: true,
    required: true
  },
  title: {
    type: String,
    require: true
  },
// Guest property is ignored
  attending: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    guest: Number, //This is being ingored and never updated 
    ref: 'User'
    }]
})
```

Second way of defining the relavant part in the schema:

```
...
//In this example the guest will be added but duplicates will occur
  user:[{
    guest: Number, // To make it clear this is not referencing anything it's just a number
    attending: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
      ref: 'User'
      }
}]
```

How do I update the type and guest properties with addToSet (to prevent duplication) in the above configuration?

```
Event.findOneAndUpdate({_id:req.body.eventId}, query)
```

Comment: Do you have any example documents? The `guest` field seems to be embedded within the `attending` field, is that design intentional?

Comment: yes I want to tie the guest field under the attending field. It's an event list where users can attend and bring guests. So each event should have the user ID and the number of guests he's bringing to the event.

Comment: It would be useful if you gave an example snippet of a thing that you'd want to persist into the DB.

Comment: Did you mean to define your schema as `attending: [{
    type: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    guest: String
    
    }]` ?

Comment: What kind of value is going to be in the 'guest' field? A string, I get it, but I mean is it a name, what does it represent in your domain?

Comment: Actually it should be a number, I've put a string type there because I'm getting the number from my form as a string and I just didn't get around to fix that yet. It should be: user id for the ref and then number of guests (without names) for he guest property

Comment: @chirdam yes you are right that should be the definition as I'm showing in my second example the problem is that there are duplication that way. And a user can add himself many times to the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you understand how mongoose schemas work, you might want to spend some more time on their documentation.

What you have provided as code is what appears to be a field called `Events` in your Schema which is an array of objects, each object of which has a single field called `attending`, which itself is required to be an ObjectId type and reference the 'User' collection.  There is also a `guest` property on the field definition which will be ignored by Mongoose as it doesn't understand what you're asking for.

Realize that what this data structure is, is instructions to Mongoose on how to validate and persist your data.  It won't generally be updated at runtime for most applications and will not store data directly, again its purpose is to give clues to Mongoose as to how you want the data stored.

/** Edit based on comments and updated question **/

As I said before, you can't directly embed another field into the definition of a field.  What you can do is create a mixed type which has both pieces of information, but that will require you to manage things yourself to some degree.

```
let EventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  date: {
    type: Date,
    unique: true,
    timestamps: true,
    required: true
  },
  title: {
    type: String,
    require: true
  },

  attendees: [{
    user : {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User'
    },
    guests : Number
  }]
})
```

Anytime anyone is added to the attending list, you'll need to call event.markModified() to make sure it gets saved.  If you don't want to allow duplicate users, you'll also need to check that.  One way to make sure that happens is to `populate()` that field when you fetch the event, then just check locally for matches.

/** Edit #2 **/

You can also explicitly create another schema to 'hold' your user and # guests information, which will then create models that Mongoose will watch, and you can apply validation to them via normal Mongoose methods and not worry about dirty checking.  That'd look like this:

```
// in ./models/attendee.js
let AttendeeSchema = new Schema({
    user : {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
      ref: 'User',
      unique : true 
      },
    guests : Number
}

mongoose.model('Attendee', AttendeeSchema);

// in your Events definition
    let Attendee    = mongoose.model('Attendee');
    let EventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      date: {
        type: Date,
        unique: true,
        timestamps: true,
        required: true
      },
      title: {
        type: String,
        require: true
      },
      attendees: [Attendee]
    })
```

/** Edit 3: Now, with queries **/

To insert a new attendee, given an existing event and a known user:

```
event.attendees.push(new Attendee({user: user, guests: 5}));
event.save(console.log);
```

To update an existing attendee, you'll need to find the one you're looking for first:

```
let attendee = event.attendees.find((attendee) => { return attendee._id.toString() === user._id.toString(); }); 
attendee.guests = 10;
event.save(console.log);
```

Comment: I think I better include the full example with some variations of what I've tried and what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I've updated the question hope it clears things up. If I use the guest property as shown in the second way addToSet will add duplicates of the user model and users will be able to include themselves many time under the same event which is of course not desired.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I thought maybe there's a way mongoose can do some of the lifting for me. What do I need the markModified() for though?

Comment: Generally, Mongoose does a lot of lifting for you.  In my example, you're persisting a "Mixed type" schema (the anonymous object with  a user and # guests), which isn't dirty checked by mongoose, b/c it doesn't know what it's looking for.  So you tell it explicitly that the field has been modified.  If you don't want to do that, you can create another schema.  I'll add that to my answer for others since I'm running out of characters.

Comment: What are the  queries to update both the attending and guest in your second example?